# Encrypting using Vigenere cipher where Plaintext is read from a file (JAVA)

Tags: java, vigenere

I am trying a simple Vigenere cipher where plain text is read from a file and encrypted using a key.

Key =ABC
Cipher text is obtained by addition between the PT and the key

Plain Text : W E W I L L A T T A C K T O N I G H T

Key   : A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A

Cipher     : W F Y I M N A U V A D M T P P I H J T

**How can i repeat the key for the length of the plain text and then encrypt it as it is being read.?**

The input is read from a file using the following snippet

```
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("/Documents/file1.txt");

    int r;
    int count = 0 ;


    //Read each character from the file one by one till EOF
    while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) 
    {
        char c = (char) r; 
      //SOMETHING NEEDS TO BE DONE HERE
    System.out.print(c); 
    count ++; //Keeps count of the number of characters in the plain text.
```

Comment: What have you tried? How would you solve this if you were doing it by hand?

Comment: I am trying to approach it as follows :Save the Plain text in an array as it is read ...save the key in an array as well of the same size and perform addition....

Comment: OK, so as you scan through the plaintext you need to keep track of where you are in the key, and when you reach the key start over again. That means maintaining two indexes, or using one modulo the length of the key. Try writing "SOMETHING", see what happens, and if it's wrong fix it until it's right. Programming is the art of debugging a blank sheet of paper.

Comment: @keshlam : hey i have found the solution. Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void encrypt (String a)throws IOException 
{

    //Array of the length of the Plain Text is created
    char pt[] = new char[count];

    //File is opened again and this time passed into the plain text array 
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("/Users/avtrulzz/Documents/file1.txt") ;

    int s ;

    int i = 0 ;

    while((s = f.read()) != -1)

    {
    //Every character read is simultaneously fed into the array
        pt[i] = (char) s ;
            i ++ ;
    }

    //Find the length of the key
    int kl = a.length() ;
    //Find how many times the key has to be repeated
    int keyrep = count / kl ;

    //Where keyrep is the number of times you want to repeat the string and a is the string  to repeat.
    String repeated = new String(new char[keyrep]).replace("\0", a);

    System.out.println("The key repeated till the length of the plain text");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(repeated);

    //The string "repeated" is made into an array "keyforpt"
    char keyforpt[] = repeated.toCharArray() ;


    char ct[] = new char[count] ;

    for(int ind = 0; ind < pt.length ; ind++)

    {
        ct[ind] = toChar((toInt(pt[ind]) + toInt(keyforpt[ind]) + 1) % 26);
    }

    System.out.println() ;
    for(int temp = 0;temp < ct.length;temp++)
        {

            System.out.print(ct[temp]) ;
        }
    System.out.println() ;
}


private static int toInt(char chr)
{
    return chr - 'a';
}

private static char toChar(int value) 
{
    return (char)(value + 'a');
}
```